# How to prevent extra hook calls on redux state change?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a custom hook: useNavigation(). It returns the target route to redirect the user if it is required.

Inside the hook I use redux store (only to read values):

```
{ prop1, prop2 } = useTypedSelector(state => state.data);
```

Where useTypedSelector code is:

```
const useTypedSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

Where TypedUseSelectorHook and useSelector hooks come from react-redux and RootState is a type of my root reducer.

**I have the following actual result**:
If redux store changes, then the change triggers unexpected useNavigation hook call.

**But my expected result is**:
useNavigation hook uses redux store to read values, but they don't triggers useNavigation hook call on change.

How to prevent extra hook calls on redux state change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always want to select the minimum amount of data that you need with `useSelector`.  Any changes to the value that is returned from `useSelector` will trigger a re-render.

You can make it marginally better by selecting `prop1` and `prop2` separately so that changes to other properties in `state.data` don't trigger re-rendering.

```
const prop1 = useTypedSelector(state => state.data.prop1);
const prop2 = useTypedSelector(state => state.data.prop2);
```

But I suspect that you can make it much better by moving some of the logic that is happening in your hook into a custom selector function instead.  You may want to use `reselect` to memoize your selector.

```
const selectTargetRoute = (state: RootState) => {
  const {prop1, prop2} = state.data;
  // do some logic
  // return a route or null/undefined
}
```

```
const useNavigation = () => {
  const targetRoute = useTypedSelector(selectTargetRoute);
  // do something with the route
}
```